# Nginx http auth ssl requires password second time with “Realm”

Tags: docker, nginx, http-authentication

Trying to make a site demo that blocks spiders using http auth.
Accessing the site correctly requests auth with "Demo" tag, but after this popup another one appears saying `The site says: “Realm”` and I cannot access my site. I don't know where does it come from.

nginx.conf:

```
server{
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/pse.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/pse.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    auth_basic           "Demo";
    auth_basic_user_file conf/demo_passwd;
    location / {
        resolver 127.0.0.11; #docker dns
        #workaround to defer resolving container name after it starts
        set $target http://web:80;
        proxy_pass $target;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Note that I am using a self signed dev ssl sertificate.

Using docker image: nginx:1.17.3-alpine